# Google Sheet Popup message Function

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

In google sheet i created a custom button and assigned script function `showPopup` so when i click this button it runs below code and opens a Index.html.

```
function showPopup(){

  let messagehtml =HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile("index")

  SpreadsheetApp.getUi()

  .showModalDialog(messagehtml , "")
```

But how to make it open few other html files based on the drop down list by clicking the same button with `showPopup` function.

Ex. in A5  cell i created a dropdown list `Sample 1, Sample 2, Sample 3`

So if i select `Sample 2` in `A5` and if i click same button it should open `Index2` html file in popup.

again if i select `Sample 3` in `A5` and if i click same button it should open `Index3` html file in popup

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe your goal is as follows.

- You want to use the HTML file by selecting the value at the dropdown list of the cell "A5".

In this case, how about the following sample script?

#### Sample script:

```js
function showPopup() {
  const sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  if (sheet.getSheetName() != "Sheet1") return; // Please set the sheet name.
  const obj = { "Sample 1": "index1", "Sample 2": "index2", "Sample 3": "index3" };
  const value = sheet.getRange("A5").getValue();
  if (!obj[value]) return;
  let messagehtml = HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile(obj[value]);
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showModalDialog(messagehtml, "sample");
}
```

- In this script, the value is retrieved from the dropdown list at the cell "A5" and the HTML file is used by the value of the dropdown list.